# The backup GPT table is corrupt - How to recover data

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery

Ran:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and got the following output:

```
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sdb: 298,1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 00004786-5ED3-0000-406A-0000AF1E0000
```

Used:

```
sgdisk -b sdb-backup.gpt /dev/sdb
```

And right after ran:

```
 sudo gdisk /dev/sdb
```

After this i selected option "v" and got this:

```
Caution: The CRC for the backup partition table is invalid. This table may
be corrupt. This program will automatically create a new backup partition
table when you save your partitions.

Identified 1 problems!
```

Which wasn't very conclusive, either way i entered the p following the w command and finally got this:

```
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sdb.
Unable to save backup partition table! Perhaps the 'e' option on the experts'
menu will resolve this problem.
Warning! An error was reported when writing the partition table! This error
MIGHT be harmless, or the disk might be damaged! Checking it is advisable.
```

As this is an old macbook disk, i installed hfsutils and ran:

```
sudo fsck.hfs /dev/sdb
```

Still not being able to mount the disk, i opened gparted and it is for quite some time "searching /dev/sdb partitions..."

I really would like to recover some data that's present in the disk . Is there any advice or any tip you can point out?

thank you.

Comment: Use `ddrescue` or `dd_rescue` or whatever and pray.

Comment: It's now running and creating the IMG file . It is darn slow! After the image is done , i imagine the filesystem must be intact in order to see it folder by folder. What are the odds of that? And what can i do with the data extracted even if i can't mount the image? Theoretically the bytes i have there are what i'm looking for

Comment: Why would you run fsck on the block device rather than on the right partition?